# How to use lambda expression in C# application?

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to use lambda expression to get `CountryName` in my C# application. Currently throwing error

> The parameterized query '(@CountryCode varchar(8000))exec GetCountry @CountryCode' expects the parameter '@CountryCode', which was not supplied.

Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

```
 string CountryName = Loctn().Where(r => r.Country_Code == "AU").Select(y => y.CountryName).ToString(); //throws error
```

Comment: Your `Loctn()` method just initializes a new `LoctnModel` which will have `Country_Code` = `null` (hence the error).

Comment: @StephenMuecke, how to fix this? Please suggest me.

Comment: Pass the value to the method (via a parameter). But then there is no point using the `.Where()` as well. And your `.ToString()` makes no sense either

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you so much. Solved it.